# Find string using regular expression, and reuse said string with new surrounding text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've searched Hi and low, but couldn't find an exact answer to what i'm trying to do...

I'd like to find any text with  __ in the beginning and /__ at the end (`i.e. "in the middle of the sentence __this/__ could be underlined, and __this(!) can also/__ be underlined")`. so, it can be one word, or a few, with any characters in there, including spaces. There could be different words and combination - in the same paragraph - starting with  __  and ending with /__ .

Once found, i'd like to remove the __ and /__ and replace them with HTML - for example, a div tag.
so:

```
__sample string /__
```

should be:

```
<div>sample string</div>
```

I know i'm supposed to use capturing groups, but i can't find a way to do this.

javascript:
`.match` seems to match, and put the results in an array - but how do i go back into the string and replace the found results?

jquery:
`.replace` should work for this, but i'm not sure how to reference the found string, and surround it...

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need match but you need `String#replace`:

```
s='in the middle of the sentence __this/__ could be underlined, and __this(!) can also/__ be underlined';
var repl = s.replace(/__(.*?)\/__/g, "<div>$1</div>");
//=> in the middle of the sentence <div>this</div> could be underlined, and <div>this(!) can also</div> be underlined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It's a slight variation of something we have working here.  I modified the replace part...but didn't actually test it.  If you need to find more than one occurrence, I suppose you could pass-in a new starting index which would be the index of where you left off from the first time.

```
    public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
    {
        int Start, End;
        if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
        {
            Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
            End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
            return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    string betweenString = getBetween(sourceString, "__", "/__");

    sourceString = sourceString.Replace("__"+betweenString+"/__", "<div>"+betweenString+"</div>");
```